# Kubernetes: Deploy daemon set to all nodes except for master node

Tags: kubernetes

I have kubernetes running on version 1.5 with two nodes and one master nodes. I would like to deploy fluentd as a daemon set onto all nodes, but the master node (the master node spams warning messages as it can't find logs). How can I avoid deploying to the master node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `label` for your slave nodes and use that label in a `selector` for the daemon set, which will only deploy on the nodes that have that label.

Inversely, you can define a negative selector to assign the daemon set to pods that don't have a label. In your case, the pod that doesn't have the master's label.

Comment: We ended up adding a label to all nodes that we wanted to deploy on and used a node selector for them. How would we use a negative selector?

Comment: from the doc, you should be able to do `!=`  https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#equality-based-requirement

Comment: my bad, it seems it's only for lookup, not for definition.

Answer (score 2):

So to make a pod not schedule on a master node you need to add the following

```
nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/role: node
```

This will make the pod schedule on only nodes. The above example shows the default label for node in kops provisioned cluster. Please very the key value if you have have provisioned the cluster from a different provider

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the Taints and Tolerations features. Using these you can define that given node in "tainted" in particular way preventing pods scheduling on this node unless they have a toleration matching that taint.

Comment: This did not work:

tolerations:
        - key: "kubernetes.io/role"
          operator: "Equal"
          value: "master"
          effect: "NoSchedule"